# Constructor parameter for injected class

Tags: ninject

Let's say I would like to inject an implementation of this interface:

```
interface IService { ... }
```

implemented as:

```
class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService(string s) { }
}
```

in an instance of this class:

```
class Target
{
    [Inject]
    public IService { private get; set; }
}
```

I do the injection by calling `kernel.Inject(new Target())`, but what if I would like to specify the parameter `s` of the constructor depending on some context when calling `Inject`?
Is there a way to achieve such context-dependant service initialization at injection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply done using parameters...

```
kernel.Inject(new Target(), new ConstructorArgument("s", "someString", true));
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In most cases you should not use *Field Injection*, it should be
   used only in rare cases of circular dependencies.
2. You should only use the *kernel* once at the start of your
   application and never again.

Example Code:

```cs
interface IService { ... }

class Service : IService
{
    public Service(string s) { ... }
}

interface ITarget { ... }

class Target : ITarget
{
    private IService _service;

    public Target(IServiceFactory serviceFactory, string s)
    {
        _service = serviceFactory.Create(s);
    }
}

interface ITargetFactory
{
    ITarget Create(string s);
}

interface IServiceFactory
{
    IService Create(string s);
}

class NinjectBindModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public NinjectBindModule()
    {
        Bind<ITarget>().To<Target>();
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
        Bind<ITargetFactory>().ToFactory().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IServiceFactory>().ToFactory().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindModule());
        var targetFactory = kernel.Get<ITargetFactory>();
        var target = targetFactory.Create("myString");
        target.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The string I pass to the constructor is not constant and changes at each instantiation.
I studied the factory approach before, but there is one aspect that bothers me; the whole point of using DI in my case is to abstract 'Service' behind a 'IService', and wiring these two is done through a binding. But the factory somehow hardwires them by using a 'Service' where the 'Target' requires a 'IService'... Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: I am not following you, iv read your comment a 100 times now an i'm still not sure what you mean. sorry...

Comment: Haha, don't be sorry, I was probably not that clear.
If you refer to my initial post, I try to inject a IService in my Target object. Actual implementation of IService can vary - it can be that MyService class with a constructor parameter, but it can be any other and the binding is done using Ninject's kernel.Bind<IService>().To<MyService>().
Now if I look at the implementation of your TargetFactory, it returns a 'new Target(new Service(s))' as a ITarget, hence hardcoding the bind of IService to Service...
Well, maybe it's still not that clear! :)

Comment: Ah, well it was just an example, you could either use a factory in the factory for getting an IService objects, or you could use an IProvider. and you can also set which implementation to inject into different classes in the bindings with `WhenInjectedInto<ITarget>()`